# How in Java find dates for previous 2 mondays?

Tags: java, date, time

May be like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

if (cal.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK==1){
System.out.println(cal.cal.getTime())
```

But may be exists more simple way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7); // First week before
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7); // Second week before
```

Let me make this work for just Mondays.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

int weekday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int days = (Calendar.SATURDAY - weekday + 2) % 7;

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);
```

Comment: This doesn't necessary give monday as result?

Answer (score 1):

Even simpler would be to set the weekday directly:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Please keep in mind, that this does not effect the time. If you want 00:00, you need to set the appropriate values:

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

Use a TemporalAdjuster.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

LocalDate previousOrSameMonday = today.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) );
```

And subtract a week to get a second one.

```
LocalDate secondMondayBefore = previousOrSameMonday.minusWeeks( 1 );
```