# Java - get Monday date of a week give a date in that week

Tags: java, calendar

I got a date `YYYY-MM-DD` how can I get the Monday date of that date whatever the given date is?

Edited: got the answer from [How in Java find dates for previous 2 mondays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957405/how-in-java-find-dates-for-previous-2-mondays).

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307884/retrieve-current-weeks-mondays-date) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LocalDate monday = 
    localDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
```